# Ruby on Rails With mysql2 on Windows x64 and Xampp - Cannot create model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have installed gem "mysql2" but when I tried to create new model follow this code:

rails generate model Article title:string text:text

I met errors and files cannot be created:

```
    c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG
    ] Segmentation fault
    ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x64-mingw32]

    -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
    c:0020 p:-10099526 s:0068 e:000067 TOP    [FINISH]
    c:0019 p:---- s:0066 e:000065 CFUNC  :require
    c:0018 p:0083 s:0062 e:000061 TOP    c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mys
    ql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8 [FINISH]
    c:0017 p:---- s:0060 e:000059 CFUNC  :require
    c:0016 p:0037 s:0056 e:000055 BLOCK  c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bun
    dler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76 [FINISH]
    c:0015 p:---- s:0053 e:000052 CFUNC  :each
    c:0014 p:0055 s:0050 e:000049 BLOCK  c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bun
    dler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72 [FINISH]
    c:0013 p:---- s:0043 e:000042 CFUNC  :each
    c:0012 p:0030 s:0040 e:000039 METHOD c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bun
    dler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61
    c:0011 p:0013 s:0036 e:000035 METHOD c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bun
    dler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133
    c:0010 p:0047 s:0032 e:000031 TOP    d:/www/skygalleon/sns/config/application.rb
    :7 [FINISH]
    c:0009 p:---- s:0030 e:000029 CFUNC  :require
    c:0008 p:0014 s:0026 e:000025 METHOD c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rai
    lties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146
    c:0007 p:0015 s:0023 e:000022 METHOD c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rai
    lties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:133
    c:0006 p:0009 s:0019 e:000018 METHOD c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rai
    lties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51
    c:0005 p:0033 s:0016 e:000015 METHOD c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rai
    lties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40
    c:0004 p:0116 s:0012 e:000011 TOP    c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rai
    lties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17 [FINISH]
    c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :require
    c:0002 p:0034 s:0004 E:0025c8 EVAL   bin/rails:4 [FINISH]
    c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0000f8 TOP    [FINISH]

    bin/rails:4:in `'
    bin/rails:4:in `require'
    c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:
```